# Datepicker in wrong format "formatString" has no effect and warning about mask

Tags: javascript, datepicker

This is my code:

```
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
    <DatePicker
      disableFuture
      value={enddate}
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        set_enddate(newValue.toISODate());
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} />
      )}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

It works properly but the date format is 1/17/2023, I would like it to be 2023-01-17. I believe the mask error *"text-field-helper.js:31 Mask does not support numbers with variable length such as 'M'.
Either use numbers with fix length or disable mask feature with 'disableMaskedInput' prop
Falling down to uncontrolled no-mask input."*
is because the month is a 1 and not 01.

I have tried adding disableMaskedInput to the DatePicker but it has no effect. I have tried mask="yyyy-mm-dd" and formatString="yyyy-MM-dd" but none of them worked and this warning is always displayed. I believe this warning will go away when the date format is correctly displayed as yyyy-mm-dd but I have not managed to do that. The enddate is a iso date string and the datepicker is correctly reading it as its first value.

Comment: toISODate ? you keep date in this format in set_enddate. Change this to UTC

Comment: @Robert yes it should be an iso string. There are other functions that needs that. This datepicker is in reality only needed to get a "yyyy-mm-dd" formated string from the user in a user friendly way

Comment: so why you don't make helper function which will format date to expect one ?